# What does dimension in integer programing problem mean

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

In the problem P1 below described in a research paper I am reading, the authors say that the problem P1 below is a three dimensional integer programing programing problem. Can I ask what does 3-dimension means here? does it mean that it has three min/max functions or three or the fact that it depends on three variables $a\in A, n\in N,$ and $, m \in M$.

[Explanation of Problem P1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARFYE.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a 3D problem because you have three variables here, $n, m, k$.

Comment: Actually, it's one variable ($a$) but three indices, meaning $a\in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace ^ {|\mathcal{N}||\mathcal{M}||\mathcal{K}|}$.